# "self.data" usage in python

Tags: python, attributes

Hello I have a question about attribute usage in Python. I learned that in function definition we can assign some new attributes for objects for example: self! However, when try to use that I got an error which is "... instance has no attribute 'data'

```
class Lazy:
    def __call__(self, num):
            if num is None:
                    return self.data
            # It changes the current object in-place,
            # by reassigning the self attribute.
            else:
                    self.data += num
```

This is my little code.
I'm very new at this. I couldn't figured out what is wrong.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Should give it a initial value before the first usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only assigning `self.data` if `num is None`, so it can happen that you try to access it before it has been assigned. To prevent this, you could initialize it in the constructor:

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 0

    def __call__(self, num):
        if num is None:
            return self.data
        else:
            self.data += num
```

Here's  what sequence of events causes your error:

1. You create a new instance of your class. At this point, Python knows nothing about `self.data`:

   ```
   lazy = Lazy()
   ```
2. You call it passing `None`:

   ```
   lazy(None)
   ```
3. Now, Python enters `__call__` and because the if condition evaluates to `True` it tries to return `self.data`. Wait a minute... it still doesn't know what `self.data` is... so it spits out an error.

In order to prevent this, you always have to assign your attributes before trying to do something with their values (for instance, returning them from a function). It doesn't have to be in the constructor: just before the first time Python tries to access the attribute. This is true for *any* variable, i.e. the following is impossible:

```
print(a) # How do you expect Python to know the value of a?
a = 5    # too late to assign it now...
```

Comment: Do I have to initialize this way every time when I assign an attribute? or is it just for "self" @codesparkle

Comment: @user2094920 I've added an explanation. Is this what you were wondering about?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference `self.data` however not initialized/declared it.

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self, data=0):
        self.data = data #You are initializing data to 0 or a user specified value

    def __call__(self, num):
        if num is None:
            return self.data
            # It changes the current object in-place,
            # by reassigning the self attribute.
        else:
            self.data += num
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to modify `self.data`, you must first initialize the `self.data` attribute by using the special `__init__` method for classes.

From the official documentation:

> object.__init__(self[, ...])
>
> > Called when the instance is created. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression.

So you could set `self.data` to 0, then your `__call__` method should work as written.

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 0

    def __call__(self, num):
        if num is None:
            return self.data
        else:
            self.data += num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can init the attribute in `__init__()` method, or anywhere else (although `__init__()` is the recommended place).

Try `self.data` and initialize it if it doesn't exist.

```
class Lazy:
    def __call__(self, num):
            try:
                self.data
            except:
                self.data = 0
            if num is None:
                    return self.data
            # It changes the current object in-place,
            # by reassigning the self attribute.
            else:
                    self.data += num
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that in your code:

```
class Lazy:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = 0

def __call__(self, num):
    if num is None:
        return self.data
```

suppose if you call your instance like: `lazy(some_value)` then your else branch will execute which evaluates to:

```
    else:
        self.data += num # self.data = self.data + num
```

but, there may be the case in which self.data may be undefined in that case too it will through the above error.

I agree with all the above answers but I needed to focus this corner case too.

enjoy!